# Mongoose - Update field in nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection that looks like this

```
{
  "_id":ObjectId("58a5a40663d24e0498ecf5e1"),
  "picture":null,
  "close":{
    "hour":19,
    "minute":30
  },
  "open":{
    "hour":7,
    "minute":0
  },
  "location":{
    "latitude":-6.304718,
    "longitude":106.64337
  },
  "address":"abcd",
  "placeName":"xyz",
  "floor":[
    {
      "number":1,
      "slot":[
        {
          "id":"A1",
          "availability":true
        },
        {
          "id":"A2",
          "availability":true
        },
        {
          "id":"A3",
          "availability":true
        },
        {
          "id":"A4",
          "availability":true
        },
        {
          "id":"A5",
          "availability":true
        },
        {
          "id":"B1",
          "availability":true
        },
        {
          "id":"B2",
          "availability":true
        },
        {
          "id":"B3",
          "availability":true
        },
        {
          "id":"B4",
          "availability":true
        },
        {
          "id":"B5",
          "availability":true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "number":3,
      "slot":[
        {
          "id":"A1",
          "availability":true
        },
        {
          "id":"A2",
          "availability":true
        },
        {
          "id":"A3",
          "availability":true
        },
        {
          "id":"B4",
          "availability":true
        },
        {
          "id":"B5",
          "availability":true
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "__v":0
}
```

And now I want to update one of the 'availability' field which the slot.id matches the give query.

When I want to update with this code

```
ParkingPlace.findOneAndUpdate({
  '_id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(placeID),
  'floor': {
    $elemMatch: {
      'number': body.floor
    }
  },
  'floor.slot': {
    $elemMatch: {
      'id': body.slot
    }
  }
}, {
  $set: {
    'slot.$.availability': false
  }
}, function (err, docs) {
  if (err) {
    res.json(err);
  } else {
    res.json(docs);
  }
});
```

It returns the doc, which **should** mean it succeeds, but the 'availability' field in the database is still not updated.

Does anyone know why and how to fix it?

**Edit:
What I mean is that the 'availability' field on the database is still set to true even though I already set it to false.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`new` option](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate):

> new: bool - if true, return the modified document rather than the
>   original. defaults to false (changed in 4.0)

```
ParkingPlace.findOneAndUpdate({
  '_id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(placeID),
  'floor': {
    $elemMatch: {
      'number': body.floor
    }
  },
  'floor.slot': {
    $elemMatch: {
      'id': body.slot
    }
  }
}, {
  $set: {
    'slot.$.availability': false
  }
}, {
  new: true
}, function (err, docs) {
  if (err) {
    res.json(err);
  } else {
    res.json(docs);
  }
});
```

Comment: what I mean is that even in the database, the 'availability' field is still set to true, even though I have set it to false